# POPUP menu not send WM_COMMAND message

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, contextmenu, visual-c++-6, popupmenu

I am using vc6.0. I load a popmenu when right click to a listbox item. But it seems not send WM_COMMAND message when I click the popmenu item. I dont have any clue about this after seaching in google. Does anyone knows?

```
void PT_OnContextMenu(HWND hwnd, HWND hwndContext, UINT xPos, UINT yPos)
{
    HWND hList = GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_LIST_PRESTYPE);
    if (hList == hwndContext)
    {
        if(-1!=indexLB)
        {
            RECT rect;  
            POINT pt;  
            pt.x = xPos;
            pt.y = yPos;
            ListBox_GetItemRect(hwndContext, indexLB, &rect);
            ScreenToClient(hwndContext, &pt);
            if(PtInRect(&rect, pt))
            {                 
                HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu((HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU_RDELTYPE));                  
                if(hMenu)  
                {  
                    HMENU hpop = GetSubMenu(hMenu,0);  
                    ClientToScreen(hwndContext, &pt);  
                    TrackPopupMenu(hpop,  
                        TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,  
                        pt.x,  
                        pt.y,  
                        0,  
                        hwndContext,  
                        NULL);  
                    DestroyMenu(hMenu);  
                }  
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Not get Message Box at code below.

```
void PT_OnCommand(HWND hwnd, int id, HWND hwndCtl, UINT codeNotify)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case ID_MENUITEM_RDELTYPE:
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd,TEXT("dddd！"),TEXT("dddd"),MB_OK);
        }
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Found it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
A handle to the window that owns the shortcut menu. This window receives all messages
from the menu. The window does not receive a WM_COMMAND message from the menu until the
function returns. If you specify TPM_NONOTIFY in the uFlags parameter, the function does
not send messages to the window identified by hWnd. However, you must still pass a window
handle in hWnd. It can be any window handle from your application.
```

I set `hwnd` as listbox not the dialog.